# Eagerly fetching and filtering an association

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jpa, spring-data

I use lazy loading with all relationships but for performance reasons I want to use eager loading for 1 association in 1 query.

I can't use the `FETCH` keyword to force eager loading for this association, because I want to be able to filter this association too and this is not supported by the specification.

What is the simplest way to achieve this thing?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a different join for the filtering:

```
select u from User u
left join fetch u.address fetchedAddress
inner join u.address filteredAddress
where filteredAddress.street = :street
```

Comment: I can't do that because one entity may have thousands of related entities. That's why I want to filter those

Comment: So, you mean you want JPA to load users with only some of its addresses? That's precisely what the spec forbids. You should load the addresses instead, and get the users from the loaded addresses.